# Is it "x- and y-directions" or "x- and y-direction"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Consider the following sentence:

```
We perform the filtering process in the x- and y-directions sequentially.
```

Is 'directions' correct in this case? I believe it is, but 'direction' is very commonly used.

Comment: You should specify what the original, unshortened sentence would be. I assume since you are asking the question at all that the original would be "x-direction and y-direction."

Comment: that's actually the original sentence.

Answer (score -1):

The [suspended hyphen](https://ontariotraining.net/suspended-hyphen/) is used to indicated a missing word that is shared between two or more hyphenated constructions in a list. When you use a suspended hyphen, the shared word does not change.

In your case, it depends on what the complete sentence is intended to be.

If you intend, "We perform the filtering process in the x-directions and y-directions sequentially," then you would indeed shorten it to "We perform the filtering process in the x- and y-directions sequentially."

If, however, the complete sentence should be, "We perform the filtering process in the x-*direction* and y-*direction* sequentially," then you would shorten it without changing the shared word:

**We perform the filtering process in the x- and y-direction sequentially.**

Comment: The full sentence is given, but the intended meaning is the latter example you give, rather than the former.

Comment: It would probably then be good to clarify the source and context in your original question. If the latter ("x-direction and y-direction") is intended, then the sentence you have given is suspended incorrectly.

Answer (score -1):

I think..

We perform the filtering process in the x- and y-directions sequentially.

We perform the filtering process in the x- or y-direction sequentially.

So, in the case of your sentence, "directions" is OK.

Comment: Can you quote some references to substantiate this answer?  As it stands, we have no idea whether you've researched this thoroughly or are merely guessing.